# How can I access dynamic object members in ViewBag of view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have assigned ViewBag in actionresult with dynamic object as shown below

```
ViewBag.viewBagModel = new { code = "P8c93E0NlQ8c0xE=", userRole = Student, schoolCode = 1000, schoolName = "New School 1_change", standardName = "LKG", sectionName = "B", associatedStudent = null }
```

And I am able to get values by name in controller/actionresult for ex:

```
ViewBag.viewBagModel.code // will return "P8c93E0NlQ8c0xE="
```

But when I am trying same in View I am getting error stating

> "{"'object' does not contain a definition for 'code'"}"

More info : syntax of this dynamic object

```
new {string code, string userRole, int? schoolCode, string schoolName, string standardName,string sectionName, string user}
```

I wish to fetch this object data in View.

Comment: Have you tried using `ViewData`?

Comment: Not sure whether you can even do this (putting dynamic object into already dynamic context) but you can simply create a class holding these properties and pass ViewBag a strongly typed instance of that class. Not super shiny but will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is of an anonymous type. You will not be able to access it directly in the view. You can still get it working in a different way.

Your view model needs to be of type `dynamic`:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Then change your model's code be of type `ExpandoObject` like this:

```
ViewBag.viewBagModel = new { code = "P8c93E0NlQ8c0xE=", userRole = Student, schoolCode = 1000, schoolName = "New School 1_change", standardName = "LKG", sectionName = "B", associatedStudent = null }.ToExpando();
```

Note the `.ToExpando()` above. And here is the static class with the `ToExpando` method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
        public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(anonymousObject);
            IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
                expando.Add(item);
            return (ExpandoObject)expando;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ToString()` extension. I did try it now and it seems to work. That being said, I would advice you use a model that is not dynamic. Even if you already have a model for the View, you can put it in another model.

So you code will look like this

```
ViewBag.viewBagModel.code.ToString();
```

Comment: ViewBag.viewBagModel.code.ToString() didn't work for me.